# How to: callback function that takes ajax get array as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How would I go about writing a function that takes a function as a parameter and runs the callback function with an array pulled from the server as its parameter. So if I ran something like:

```
getArray(display)
```

`getArray` would retrieve an array from the server, then display would write that array into the html.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
function getArray(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        ..//options
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data); 
        }
    });
}

function display(array) {
    console.log(array);
}

//call it!
getArray(display);
```